# StackExchange broken for new user?

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-exchange, homepage

Ever since I tried to import my user account into StackExchange (I successfully did it with all of the SE subsites), I've been getting an error every time I visit the StackExchange main page. I went to log in, add OpenID, joined my Google ID, and then got that. I get redirected to https://stackexchange.com/error?aspxerrorpath=/ and shown this:

> **Oops! Something Bad Happened!**
>
> We apologize for any inconvenience,
> but an unexpected error occurred while
> you were browsing our site.
>
> It's not you, it's us. This is our
> fault.
>
> Detailed information about this error
> has automatically been recorded and we
> have been notified.
>
> Yes, we do look at every error. We
> even try to fix some of them.
>
> It's not strictly necessary, but if
> you'd like to give us additional
> information about this error, do so at
> our feedback site,
> http://meta.stackoverflow.com.

Along with an image of Sad Panda. :( If I click log in, it shows my name and shows me as logged in, but then going back to / errors again. In fact, all other pages of the site seem to work OK.

I wasn't going to report it at first, but it's been something like 5 hours now and I figure you might want a heads up.

Comment: I'm getting this too on the homepage. Looks like Panda had a wipeout.

Answer (score 1):

This should be fixed now.  Sorry about that.